# Android Studio - Error retrieving android device catalog

Tags: android, unit-testing, android-studio, kotlin, android-instrumentation

When I am trying to run instrument test I am getting below error.

And also getting a dialog from Android studio like,

```
Error retrieving android device catalog
```

> ```
> Testing started at 11:49 ...
> 06/18 11:49:34: Launching addition_isCorrect() 
> $ adb push /Users/----/app/build/outputs/apk/debug/app-debug.apk /data/local/tmp/com.----
> $ adb shell pm install --full -t -r "/data/local/tmp/com.----" 
> Success 
> APK installed in 1 s 898 ms 
> No apk changes detected since last installation, skipping installation of /Users/---/app/build/outputs/apk/androidTest/debug/app-debug-androidTest.apk
> Running tests
>
> $ adb shell am instrument -w -r   -e debug false -e class 'com.---.DatabaseTest#addition_isCorrect' com.---.test/android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner
> Client not ready yet. 
> Started running tests
>
> Tests ran to completion.
> ```

How to get rid of this error?